# getting syntax error when i use jsonp as data type from remote xml file

Tags: ajax, jsonp

SyntaxError: syntax error

can i find any way for fetching xml data from the remote server?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.xyz.com/GetAllSubjects.xml",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {

}

});
```

Comment: jsonp can only return javascript, not xml. You can configure your web method GetAllSubjects to return your xml as JSON instead.

Comment: but i am getting xml in response. I am getting whole xml file (strictly xml) content in response

Comment: Ok, so set your `dataType` to `XML`. But if it's a cross-domain request, it will not work unless you specify it and your remove server allows for it.

Comment: it is cross domain request thats why i used jsonp as it provides callback along with it.. i am still waiting for solution..
problem is just the syntax error which stops executing the other statements of javascript after getting response..

Comment: I'll repeat again, "jsonp can *only* return javascript, not xml". Sure, you *may* return xml/html/text/images from your server, but unless you send back a valid JSONP response, your browser will *always* throw a syntax error. xml != jsonp

Comment: ok then i have only one choice in that case
which is as per you

@  Brad M :- "You can configure your web method GetAllSubjects to return your xml as JSON instead."